# Git Bitbucket Branching Tree

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have this commit a new Git branch in bitbucket, but in the source tree its not creating a new line, what am I missing ?

[image]

Comment: Your branch is full visible when you have differences in both branches code, if you only make a branch then is normal that behaviour

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your new branch is built upon an existing branch, which means the graph of commits accessible from said new branch is a straight line.

If your previous branch adds commits of its own, then you would see different branches.

Comment: Thanks for this its make it more clearer to me @VonC